# Why InfoGainAttributeEval in Weka in not available for some data sets

Tags: weka

I can clearly see the InfoGainAttributeEval attribute evaluator for the weka data sets. But for a dataset i got externally InfoGainAttributeEval option is not activated.

Can someone explain to me why this must be happening. I want to rank my features.

Comment: As suggested below when my class was set as Nominal I was able to use the InfoGainAttributeEval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When selected (in the scenario that you are able to select "InfoGainAttributeEval"), if you double click the white space containing the text "InfoGainAttributeEval", then select capabilities, the following is presented:

```
CAPABILITIES
Class -- Missing class values, Nominal class,
Binary class

Attributes -- Empty nominal attributes, Nominal attributes,
Numeric attributes, Unary
attributes, Date attributes, Missing values,
Binary attributes

Additional
min # of instances: 1
```

When "InfoGainAttribueEval" is unavailable, I suspect that your class is not Nominal or Binary, but rather numerical.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my dataset.
Later I realized that all the attributes except the classification/target attribute must be of numerical form, while the classification/target attribute must be of type 'nominal'. (like I converted my attack_label column from int {1, 0} to str {'attack', 'normal'}.